# Proposal for active update of review queues

Tags: feature-request, review

I have enough rep on some sites to access review queues, and I have noticed that the numbers of posts shown in queues don't actively update. When I click on a queue which has say only one or two entries (or even several in case of Stack Overflow) I get the "this review has been cleared!" message. In this case, I'd like to know beforehand if a queue has been cleared, especially in case of high-velocity queues, such as Triage on SO.

Can this be implemented?

Comment: It used to work like that and had to be changed because of poor performance to more aggressively cache the counts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be implemented obviously, and it used to be. On other sites than the major three sites it doesn't seem a problem but on the major three, specifically StackOverflow it is: the performance of calculating the number of review items over and over again is just terrible.

That's why it is disabled everywhere.